# One domain (www.example.com) different paths (/ vs. /server2) go to different servers?

Tags: dns, server

I'm wondering if it's possible to host an application on one server (S1) with the root directory of a domain (example.com/) as its approot, but have a TOTALLY DIFFERENT application on another server (S2) with its approot pointing to a specific *path* of the same domain (example.com/server2).

I'm not talking about subdomains; I'm not talking about load-balancing one application. I'm talking about example.com/* pages on S1, and example.com/server2/* pages on S2. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the term "approot", but suspect it is the name of some configuration at the webserver end. It's better to think about these kinds of question from the other end: how will a message get from the browser to the right server. The user gives the browser a URL; the hostname in the URL is looked up in DNS to find an IP address; an HTTP request is sent to that IP address, with the requested path in it.

So ultimately, you have to have some server (or set of interchangeable servers) serving the whole of example.com, because that's the only part that will be looked up in DNS.

That server could, however, be a *proxy*, which looks at each request it receives, and passes it on to another server based on some configured rules.